# Linking error VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker

I download Neoncube downloader and tried to compile. After I resolved some linking issues, there's still three that I can't solve.

> 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol _UnEmbedBrowserObject
>   referenced in function "long **stdcall
>   NoticeWindowProcedure(struct HWND**
>   *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?NoticeWindowProcedure@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z)
>
> 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol _EmbedBrowserObject
>   referenced in function "long **stdcall
>   NoticeWindowProcedure(struct HWND**
>   *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?NoticeWindowProcedure@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z)
>
> 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol _DisplayHTMLPage
>   referenced in function "void **cdecl
>   drawNotice(struct HWND** *,int)"
>   (?drawNotice@@YAXPAUHWND__@@H@Z)

These functions appear to be from some obscure COM object from Microsoft. Yet I can't found any documentation on it. (UnEmbedBrowserObject, EmbedBrowserObject, DisplayHTMLPage)

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not names in any of the Microsoft SDK libraries.  The appear to come from [this code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/cwebpage.aspx?msg=2101476).  It could also be [this one](http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/I-N/ieprogram/article.php/c4379).  You'll have to build it to create the DLL and add the .lib it produces to your project's linker input.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't notice it was the DLL that contained the functions. The documentation for the project is really bad. I shouldn't be working 6 in the morning. Thanks again!